# GetWriteWatch() in C#?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm trying to monitor a process for memory changes with a timer. So I saw that the `GetWriteWatch` API gives me the changed pages. But I can't find an example in .NET. Can someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make the call through the [Platform Invoke (P/Invoke) layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which allows you to make calls to COM components, as well as functions exported from DLLs, such as [`GetWriteWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) contains listings of Windows API P/Invoke signatures pre-defined in C# so you don't have to figure it out yourself.  [It provides the following](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetWriteWatch.html) for the `GetWriteWatch` function:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetWriteWatch(uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
   UIntPtr dwRegionSize, out IntPtr lpAddresses, ref UIntPtr lpdwCount,
   out uint lpdwGranularity);
```

Comment: I saw this, but I'm stucked on the lpAddresses pointer. Cause it needs array not simply IntPtr.

Comment: @blez: I'm looking into it now, as there's no clear indicator as to who is responsible for the allocation/deallocation of it.

Comment: As the documentation for lpAddress indicates, the application is responsible for allocating it via `VirtualAlloc` and freeing it via `VirtualFree`.

Comment: @Raymond: That's just for the `lpBaseAddress` parameter, it states specifically "this address" for that parameter; there is no mention of `VirtualAlloc` or `VirtualFree` for the `lpAddress` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, misread. `lpAddress` is just an output buffer. Caller provides the memory, the function fills it with data. In this case, you need to pass an array of IntPtrs. The pinvpke us taking a shortcut on the assumption that you're going to ask for only one address.

Comment: @Raymond: I wish they would get their wording right; I read "A pointer to a buffer that *receives* an array" as having it assigned to.

Comment: The text is saying that the buffer is filled with (receives) an array of pointers. you give it a block of memory, the function puts an array in that memory block. If it allocated an array, the parameter would have been declared as "PVOID **lpAddreses" (double indirection).